# how i can pagenate data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

i have 6825 invoices in data base i want to pagenate 10 records per page

**and in blade i want links like this (Prev, 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 .. 78 (upto last) next)**

the code which i am using now in controller

```
public function index()
    {
    $ids = [10 , 20 ,30 ]
    $invoices = Invoice::whereIn('user_id', $ids)->where($cond)->paginate(10);
    return view('approved_invoices', compact('invoices'));
}
```

and blade

```
<tbody>
              @foreach($invoices as $invoice)
               <tr>
                  <td> {{ $invoice->subtotal }}</td>
               </tr>
              @endforeach
</tbody
```

i am getting only 10 records form 6825 how i can show link pages?

Comment: Have you gone through [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination) about pagination? It's pretty extensive.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination would be a great starting point. You are only seeing 10 records because that is the first page. You can use `{{ $invoice->links() }}` to generate the links like you want using bootstrap or tailwind css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `links()` method on your results, that's why you are only getting 10 results. Add this after your `foreach` loop:

```
$invoices->links();
```

You can read more about pagination on [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results).